# Customisation search form (as on stackoverflow) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, field

Hello dear users of the stackoverflow!

I really like the search form on this website, which is stretched when the user starts typing characters. I tried to understand the script myself, but my knowledge is insufficient for this purpose. As I understand it is implemented using jquery. And I'm curious - are there any demo examples of such implementation (as an option from the site of the jquery framework)?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using an *HTML* form, you can use *jQuery* to animate the field.

I've created a basic form and simple jQuery script below. As for actually handling the search, you'll need another page to submit the form to and actually preform the search.

---

**HTML** *— Create your form and search field.*

```
<form action='search.php' method='POST'>
<input type='search' name='searchQuery' id='inputSearch' placeholder='Search the site'>
</form>
```

**jQuery** *— Check for a keypress(), if the field is not expanded already: animate it larger and set a variable to stop it from repeating the animation. Checking if the field has gone out of focus with blur(), animate the field to be normal sized and set a variable to indicate the field can be expanded again.*

```
var isExpanded = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputSearch').keypress(function () {
        if (isExpanded == false) {
            $(this).animate({width: 500}, 'slow');
            isExpanded = true;
        }
    });

    $('#inputSearch').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({width: 150}, 'slow');
        isExpanded = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You gave me incredible support. I do not know how to thank you. Please accept my sincere thanks! 
By the way excuse my broken English - it is not the native language ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

```
var expandedWidth = "350px",
    width = "200px";

//Expand the input el when user types first character
$("#input").keypress(function(){
    width = this.style.width;
    if(width !== expandedWidth){
        this.style.width = expandedWidth;
    }
});

//Set it back to the default/initial width when it loses focus
$("#input").blur(function(){
    this.style.width = width;
});
```

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/6/)**